# imageSourceModule.fromFile(path) returns null in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

Code is:

```
let folder = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.currentApp();

let path = fileSystemModule.path.join(folder.path,img.src.android);

let abc = imageSourceModule.fromPath(path);
```

Comment: I don't think `img.src.android` will be a string here, it would probably be a `Bitmap` so your `join` statement will be invalid.

Comment: How to solve that??

Comment: How do you create `img.src`, it was from path you already have path.

Comment: let img = new Image();
img.src = selected;

      this.images.push(img);
      alert(this.images);
      let folder = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.currentApp();
      alert(JSON.stringify(folder));
      let path = fileSystemModule.path.join(folder.path,img.src.android);
      alert(path); let abc = imageSourceModule.fromFile(path);
      alert(abc);

Comment: What is selected again? If it from any image picker, it would give you an image-asset, you won't have a path until you write it to a file.

Comment: How to convert that imageAsset to base64 string to upload on server??

Comment: On the `ImageSource` you could directly call [toBase64String](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource#tobase64string).

Comment: let image = selected.toBase64String("png");

Comment: Please do not comment comments asking for clarification or additional information: edit your post. (*Especially* with multi-line code.)